# Python Clicking Redfin Favorite and X-Out Button

Tags: python, button, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

For personal use I want to click on the Favorites or X-Out buttons of Redfin with my Python Selenium code, but I can't programmatically locate either button and I've tried for 2 days. I can see buttons with Chrome inspector but I can't locate them with the code and I've tried everything, I really have. I am just stuck and need help.

Please show me how I can locate each button, identify their selection status (selected/unselected) and how to click on them to make them toggle the selection back and forth.

I'm not new to Python or Selenium, but I am really stumped on this one. I'm accessing Chrome using the remote debugging method, which is really nice once you get it figure out. It lets me log in using my Google account, otherwise it was impossible to login like that using Selenium.

Thanks for your help.

Here is a test link https://www.redfin.com/TX/Roanoke/61-Cortes-Dr-76262/home/169577463
and html snippet from the site:

```
<div class="actions force-sideBarRightRail">
<div class="bp-HomeControls">
<div class="bp-pill-container-variant">
<div class="FavoriteButtonCopFlyoutWrapper HomeControlButtonWrapper">
<div class="bp-favoriteButtonWrapper bp-HomeActionsButton" data-rf-test-id="abp-favoriteButton">
<button type="button" class="bp-Button bp-homeActionButton bp-Button__type--ghost bp-Button__size--compact" tabindex="0" aria-label="Favorite this home">
<span class="ButtonIcon">
<svg class="bp-SvgIcon favorite bp-SvgIcon__size--medium">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="a bunch of number here"/>
</svg>
</svg>
</span>
<span class="ButtonLabel">
Favorite</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="HomeControlButtonWrapper">
<div class="bp-xOutButtonWrapper bp-HomeActionsButton">
<button type="button" class="bp-Button bp-homeActionButton bp-Button__type--ghost bp-Button__size--compact" tabindex="0">
<span class="ButtonIcon">
<svg class="bp-SvgIcon xout bp-SvgIcon__size--medium">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="a bunch of numbers here"/>
</svg>
</svg>
</span>
<span class="ButtonLabel">
X-Out</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ShareButtonCopFlyoutWrapper HomeControlButtonWrapper">
<div class="bp-shareButtonWrapper bp-HomeActionsButton" data-rf-test-name="abp-shareButton">
<button type="button" class="bp-Button bp-homeActionButton bp-Button__type--ghost bp-Button__size--compact" tabindex="0">
<span class="ButtonIcon">
<svg class="bp-SvgIcon share bp-SvgIcon__size--medium">
<svg viewBox="0 0 25 24">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="a bunch of numbers here"/>
</svg>
</svg>
</span>
<span class="ButtonLabel">
Share</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one tested way to click on the `Favourite` button:

```
## [..] your imports
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
## [..] define your driver, then

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
url = 'https://www.redfin.com/TX/Roanoke/61-Cortes-Dr-76262/home/169577463'
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Favorite this home"]'))).click()
print('clicked favourite')
```

It will print the corresponding message in the terminal, and upon click, a new overlay will be displayed, with `Favorite this home` title -- at least if you're not logged into the website, which I am not.

Lastly, see [Selenium documentation here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was banging my head and it was so simple. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome @MarkMain. I'm not sure if the other button will be as simple to locate, however it's definitely doable. Should you have any issues with it, just drop a comment, and if you can provide a test login to the website, I can help further.

Comment: Barry, what you described worked great for Favorites, but the xout is more difficult because the label does not change, the class does. Again, I worked all day trying to solve it, and failed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I realize I did not talk about the account. Redfin will accept any email address to setup a free account with them. I am hoping you would be willing to just setup an account, it's very simple and easy with them. Even a temporary email address to avoid later spam issues.

Comment: yes because I am still working on the xout which was only half of the original request. I did not want someone to think it's a complete solution. That is correct to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for the 'favorite' that builds on what Barry wrote. This code will just toggle the current setting:

```
def favorite_home():
    try:
        # If this button is found, the home is currently favorited.
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Unfavorite this home"]')))
        return True
    except:
        return False

if favorite_home():
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Unfavorite this home"]'))).click()
    print('clicked unfavorite')

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[.//span[text()="Remove from Favorites"]]'))).click()
    print('clicked remove')
else:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Favorite this home"]'))).click()
    print('clicked favorite')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code. I'm using JavaScript directly to bypass the complexities with the nested DOM elements using WebDriver's API.

```
def is_xout():
    try:
        # Use JavaScript to get the class attribute of the SVG inside the X-Out button
        script = """
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
        for (let btn of buttons) {
            if (btn.querySelector('span.ButtonLabel') && btn.querySelector('span.ButtonLabel').textContent === 'X-Out') {
                let svg = btn.querySelector('svg');
                return svg ? svg.getAttribute('class') : null;
            }
        }
        return null;
        """
        svg_class = driver.execute_script(script)
        
        if svg_class and "xout-filled" in svg_class:
            return True
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  # Output any exceptions for debugging
        return False
```